# Can you use admin pages functionality on the frontend of your site

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I posted a similar question on stack Overflow and have it gotten a reply. I want to use the woocommerce reports on the front of my site, but I don't understand the difference of how an admin page works versus the front of the site... to give this question a little more value for another reader I'll broaden the question that should solve my problem which is

Can admin functions be moved or access to the front end of a WordPress site?

Comment: You might want to link to the question on [so] you already got an answer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admin and front end are just semantics which are probably more appropriately should be called restricted access and non restricted access.

There is no magic involved in the "admin" side and you can use the same function calls to show the same information on the front end.

In practice, since you will most likely want the user to login to get access to the information, it will be probably easier to modify the admin to let the give the user access, unless you are creating your own admin screens for users which are not the site admins.

Comment: A bit more on point +1

Comment: Wow, well done Mark, the "restricted and non-restricted" analogy was a perfect description. That cleared up my doubts of where to begin, that's a great place to be mentally to start a new endeavor. I'm still new to wordpress, so I'm sure you must know my anxiety on this one. I'm going to give it a shot this evening to get one of the reports up on a frontend endpoint.